# Fill file with missing lines perl

Tags: perl

I have a file that contains the following:

```
value1;1;1
value2;2;2
value3;5;5
value4;7;7
value5;1;8
value6;3;10
value7;7;14
```

The first column contains a random value, the second column numbers 1 to 7 ordered, and the third column just consecutive numbers.
Is it possible, using perl, to fill this file in the following way:

```
value1;1;1
value2;2;2
null;3;3
null;4;4
value3;5;5
null;6;6
value4;7;7
value5;1;8
null;2;9
value6;3;10
null;4;11
null;5;12
null;6;13
value7;7;14
```

Thanks!

Comment: Provided details not enough to give a suggestion and could you please elaborate question much better brief. And have you tried anything at your end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple one-liner that does that:

```
perl -ple '($m,$n)=/;(\d+);(\d+)$/; while ($l<$n) {print "null;",++$p,";$l" if $l; $l++} $l=$n+1; $p=$m' input
```

It uses a variable (`$l`) to remember the last value of the last column and if there are gaps it fills them before outputting each line.

Output:

```
value1;1;1
value2;2;2
null;3;3
null;4;4
value3;5;5
null;6;6
value4;7;7
value5;1;8
null;2;9
value6;3;10
null;4;11
null;5;12
null;6;13
value7;7;14
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works. I modified it slightly, on the second column i need the series 1-7:   perl -ple '($n)=/;(\d+)$/; while ($l<$n) {print "null;" . $l%7 . ";$l" if $l; $l++} $l=$n+1'

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSV file, isn't it? So please, try Text::CSV_XS module! Parsers! Parser everywhere in [metacpan](http://metacpan.org)

You don't need to build parsers in Perl for practically nothing. Really!